# rheumatoid arthritis and air conditioned environment

Tags: arthritis, environmental-conditions, air-temperature, rheumatology

Can sitting in air conditioned environment ( like office ) for prolonged periods ( years ) cause joint pains ( rheumatoid arthritis )

Comment: This question needs some evidence of attempts to answer the question, or demonstration that he even looked up rheumatoid arthritis.  Joint pains don't automatically = rheumatoid arthritis, that's a specific autoimmune condition.  I realize this is feedback on an old question but I imagine that's the purpose of bumping this, to get feedback on stalled questions

Answer (score -2):

Yes, Air conditioner is one of the reason in increasing arthritis joint pain. Due to the direct blowing of unnatural cold air from AC adversely affect in joints and causes swelling. AC's cool air circulation in the room increases stiffness in the joints.

Comment: Please add some references

Comment: Hi, welcome to Health SE.  This site is different from most Q&A sites, answers are generally required to be supported by evidence.  How does cold air cause joint swelling? How does it cause stiffness?

Comment: Welcome to Health.SE. Since health is an important topic, the site has a strict policy that all answers should be [backed up with reliable references](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/should-we-require-references-to-back-up-all-answers), in order to provide the community with the means to assess the merit of the answer, regardless of the reader's background. *See [this list of reliable sources](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112/what-are-reliable-sources)*. If you still have trouble with this, feel free to visit the [help].